# How to detect a sprite radius by another sprite to attack? (Cocos2D)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Would anybody tell me how to create a radius on a sprite so that another sprite can attack when it is in that radius. Any tutorial/code will be very helpful to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`ccpDistance` from sprite.position to otherSprite.position gives you the distance between two sprites. If distance falls below a certain radius, the other sprite's position is within the radius.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you please give some links/tutorials?